# How do you visually distinct your Rails app for dev/test/production modes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Im curious how you guys visual make distinction between the different Rails modes development/test and production?

Im afraid that since visually the apps look the same in each mode, my customer can use the wrong environment and enter production data in a test environment.

Now i change the background in my application CSS, to make sure there is a difference. BUt i rather would have something smart that automatically works based on the environment thats running. Maybe a BIG watermark?

Any best practices here?

Based on Artimuz answer i did the following:

Add this to the **application_helper.rb**

```
  def development?
    @is_development ||= (ENV['RAILS_ENV'] != 'production')
  end
```

then in **application.html.erb**  i added:

```
 <head>
 <% if development? %>
    <style type="text/css">
        html {              
         background-image: url(/assets/test.png);
         background-color: silver;
        }
    </style>>   
  <% end %>
 </head>
```

The test.png is just a transparent png with the word 'test' inside and a diagonal line. Works like a charm (its tiled), for sure you you can't miss your inside the development/test environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From here: http://markmail.org/message/grmor6rppm5jwgnh

You can test RAILS_ENV environment variable.

In application_helper.rb, add this method :

```
def production?
  @is_production ||=(ENV['RAILS_ENV']=='production')
end
```

An d in your views/layouts:

```
<% if production? %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yes, you can use ERB in you CSS stylesheets, just change the file extension  to `.css.erb`. However maybe the helper method won't be accessible (but you can do the test inline : `<% if ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ...` %>)